# WCF IClientMessageInspector Logging Discrepancy Regarding Action

Tags: wcf, iclientmessageinspector

I am logging outgoing WCF Soap requests from my application, and discovered a discrepancy between what I'm logging and what actually goes out to the server via the wire.

Here is what I'm logging:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/myinterface</Action>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body>
    <myinterface xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    ...
```

Here is what actually goes out (captured with WireShark):

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
   <myinterface xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   ...
```

You'll notice that the WireShark capture does not have the Header or Action elements.

I only noticed this because I tried pushing my logged request out through SoapUI.

I'm using this code to log the request:

```
public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new WCFMessageInspector());
    }
```

And:

```
public class WCFMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{ 
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Log(request.ToString());

        return null;
    }
```

And:

```
    client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(address);
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InspectorBehavior());
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to capture exactly what is going out (verbatim), without any post-processing as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [`WCF Message Logging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `App.config` to log messages at transport level.

This should capture the message as late as possible:

> For outgoing messages, logging happens immediately after the message leaves user code and immediately before the message goes on the wire.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                      initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
         maxMessagesToLog="1000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="1000000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. This will write everything to a big text file. I want it to still go into my BeforeSendRequest method so I can have full control of the logging process.

Comment: I see. Out of interest, could you check whether this logging method actually shows a difference to what your IClientMessageInspector logs? (The problem you encounter is pretty strange IMHO. I might accept if Wireshark showed more than what you capture earlier in the stack, but **losing** headers on the way to the wire doesn't sound right...)

Comment: Yes, using your method gives the correct results. But it also wraps the XML in some additional "wrapper" elements as part of it's logging structure. I think WCF is converting the headers to an actual SOAP Action in the POST HTTP request (thus the lost header).

Comment: @johnivers I just came across this: [Perhaps a custom message encoder is the way to go for you as it is much further down in the stack.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6919711/626761).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture exact content via **[custom MessageEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder)**, unlike message inspectors (IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector) it sees original byte content including any malformed XML data.

However it's a bit harder to implement this approach. You have to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) as custom [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and adjust [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding) file to use that custom binding.

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project - [wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).