# How to intercept HTTP response code from WCF service in the client code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

So we have this "proxy" application that is both a service toward an Angular app and a client consuming a WCF service.

A request from the UI calls the proxy webApi which again calls the WCF (actually several sources but lets simplify it to one underlying service).
The WCF service can crash and thus return a non-OK HTTP status code.
The WCF service is a 3rd party so there is absolutely no way to change it.

We would like to intercept this in the proxy application but alas we cannot.
I have tried making middleware, filter attribute, exception handlers and also a custom behavior with a message inspector. No luck.
[image]

What happens is that as soon the underlying service crashes it results in an exception in the proxy application.
Our exception handler middleware catches this but we have no access to the HTTP status code that the WCF service returned.
Only the exception message gives an indication of what went wrong but we don't want to rely on parsing the text message.
This is an example of the exception message > *"The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."*

I have also tried to call a underlying webApi that i made myself - just to see if there was any differences between a WCF call and a webApi call when it comes to intercepting the underlying response HTTP status code.
It's same-same but different :)
Look like it's about getting a hook into the HTTP stack pipeline at the right place?!

So what we experience is following when debugging the proxy app:

1. request from UI is received
2. proxy makes a call to WCF service
   with another request
3. WCF service responds with non-OK status code (like
   405 or whatever)
4. exception is immediately thrown in proxy app
5. middelware exception handler catches the exception just fine - but
   no access to the wcf response HTTP status code

Notice my comments in the code below ;)

Controller:

```
    [WcfErrorHandling]
    public async Task<PersonCivilIdentifierLookupResponse1> GetKRAsync(
          PersonCivilIdentifierLookupRequest lookupRequest)
    {
        if (lookupRequest == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lookupRequest));
        }

        PersonCivilIdentifierLookup lookup = new PersonCivilIdentifierLookup
           { PersonCivilIdentifierLookupRequest = lookupRequest };

        var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        var endpoint = CreateEndpoint("***");   // URI for the underlying service removed


        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MethodsPortType>(binding, endpoint);
        var behavior = new MessageInspectorBehavior(new MessageInspector());

        channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);
        var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        // originally just used auto-generated client, but in order to add custom behavior
        // i created custom client via channelFactory above
        //using (var client = new MethodsPortTypeClient(binding, endpoint))
        {
            var response = await client.PersonCivilIdentifierLookupAsync(
                new PersonCivilIdentifierLookupRequest1(lookup));

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Message Inspector:

```
public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    int _statusCode;

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // will never go here when WCF service returns anything other that HTTP status code 200
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Attribute:

```
// seams to be totally ignored, or the exception is thrown before execution gets here
public class WcfErrorHandlingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        var statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Middleware exception handler:

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (FaultException fault)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            LogUtils.AddPropertiesToLogger(logger, httpContext);
            logger.Error(ex);
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        var feature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var x = feature?.Error;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
        {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = ex?.Message
        }.ToString());
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // tried the UseStatusCodePages as shown below
        // but it's not intercepting the response from WCF service before exception is thrown
        //app.UseStatusCodePages(builder =>
        //{
        //    builder.Run(async context =>
        //    {
        //        var response = context.Response;
        //        var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        //        var headers = response.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

        //        if (statusCode > 299)
        //        {
        //            await Task.FromException(new ApiException("KR Service har returned an error", statusCode, response.ToString(), headers, null));
        //        }
        //    });
        //});

        app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

In traditional .NET Framework i guess we could make a behavior class inheriting from WebHttpBehavior and use WebHttpBinding but they're gone i Core...

**NB. We use Core 2.2 (might upgrade in near future but i don't see core 3.0/3.1 solve this!?)**

Comment: Do you have chance to modify the WCF code? If yes you can create and `ErrorHandler` and wrap errors having status codes with a FaultContract that exposes that status code within a property..

Comment: Unfortunately the WCF is 3rd party gov data provider and there is no chance that they will change it as several other systems consume the service.
It would have been really nice to have a well formed soap message with definitions of faults etc.
Whatever we do we must do it in our own application.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919711/12354911) answer might help you. It should be applicable to .net core as well.